# How to rewrite Python code in fewer lines by using lambda one liner or similar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm looking for code to do same thing as the function below, but in fewer lines if possible. Just out of curiosity.

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    results = []
    for i in range(len(queries)):
        temp_list = queries[i]
        results.append(strings.count(temp_list))
    return results
```

This function is taking a list of strings and a list of queries. Searching for counts of queries in strings list. Creating a new list from that numbers.

Input:

```
strings = ["aaa", "abc", "zzz", "xyz", "asd", "aaa"] 
queries = ["aa", "aaa", "xyz"]
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Surely just something like `return [strings.count(x) for x in queries]`?

Comment: Get out of the habit of writing `for i in range(len(list))`, use `for item in list` instead.

Comment: Never call `count` in a loop - doing that takes quadratic time. Build a `collections.Counter` instance outside the loop and then look up counts in that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to write this in one line if you already know how to. Here I show how to arrive at the result by transforming the existing code:

1. The pattern

   ```
   for i in range(len(some_list)):
       value = some_list[i]
       # ...
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   for value in some_list:
       # ...
   ```
2. The pattern

   ```
    results = []
    for X in Y:
        results.append(f(X))
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
    results = [f(X) for X in Y]
   ```

   This is known as a *list comprehension*.

So when applying the first transformation, your code becomes

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    results = []
    for temp_list in queries:
        results.append(strings.count(temp_list))
    return results
```

and when applying the second transformation (`f` being `strings.count`), it becomes

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    return [strings.count(temp_list) for temp_list in queries]
```

<sub>Remark: `temp_list` is a bad name, as `queries` contains strings, not lists. A better name would be simply `query`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for the counts of exact matches (and not substring matches) you can use a `Counter` object to get the counts for every value in the `strings` list, then use a list comprehension to get the count for each query.

```
from collections import Counter


def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    str_counts = Counter(strings)
    return [str_counts[q] for q in queries]


s = ["aaa", "abc", "zzz", "xyz", "asd", "aaa"]
q = ["aa", "aaa", "xyz"]

print(matchingStrings(s, q))
```

For large lists of queries and strings, this will be faster than calling `count` inside the loop (or list comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension:

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    return [strings.count(item) for item in queries]
    
    
    
strings = ["aaa", "abc", "zzz", "xyz", "asd", "aaa"] 
queries = ["aa", "aaa", "xyz"] 

print(matchingStrings(strings, queries))
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 2, 1]
```